# How to set value in array depending on previous value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I've got a simple problem, but I'm struggling to find the easiest solution without transforming the array a hundred times.
I want to do a simple stacked graph in google sheets, with weeks on X and values on Y. I got the values for each week, but only for weeks, that have a value.

The values are all calculations I've done with google apps script/ js.

person1 = [[2019/37,2], [2019/42,3]] and so on, for multiple persons and for 80 weeks in total.

The num value is the total value after each week. So I want the array to be filled up with the missing weeks. Therefore I mapped this to another array, where I have all the weeks but no values, giving these weeks the value 0:

person1= [[2019/37,2],[2019/38,0],[2019/39,0],...,[2019/42,3],[2019/43,0],[2019/44,0],...]

This of course does not fit to see a progress in the graph.
So I need something to set the weeks, which were filled up, to the previous value, resulting in

person1= [[2019/37,2],[2019/38,2],[2019/39,2],...,[2019/42,3],[2019/43,3],[2019/44,3],...]

Looping through this and setting the values with something like person[i][1] == person[i-1][1] seems not to be a good practice of course.
So, what would be the best way to achieve this? I'm kind of stuck with this now, I feel like I don't see the forest for the trees.

Thanks in advance!

code:

```
let valueArray =  [[2019/37,2], [2019/42,3]]
let weeksArray = [2019/38,2019/39,2019/40,2019/41...]
//find missing weeks
let notFound = weeksArray.filter(el => valueArray.includes(el) == false).map(x => [x,0]);

//concat and sort
let outArray = arr.concat(notFound).sort((a,b)=> a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));

//output:
//[[2019/37,2],[2019/38,0],[2019/39,0],...,[2019/42,3],[2019/43,0],[2019/44,0],...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Since you already have the expanded array, you can use map on the whole array and use a function to replace the values:

```
var weeks = [[2019/37,2],[2019/38,0],[2019/39,0],[2019/40,3],[2019/41,0],[2019/42,4],[2019/43,0],[2019/44,0]];
weeks.map((a,b)=>{weeks[b][1] = (a[1] == 0 && b > 0) ? weeks[b-1][1] : weeks[b][1]});
```

To make it more readable, this is the same as:

```
weeks.forEach(function missing(item,index,arr) {
    if (item[1] == 0 && index > 0) {
      arr[index][1] = arr[index-1][1];
    }
  }
);
```

### Console log:

[image]

### References:

[Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

[Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, pretty nice. But can you tell me, why it's needed to add c as the array argument when you could also omit it and use weeks[b][1] and weeks[b-1][1] instead for the c values?

Comment: Apologies, must have missed that when converting my forEach statement. Edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, was offline the whole week. Ok, but your first solution works as well. But it would bloat every function call and is therefore unwanted, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
function fixArray() {
  var array = [["2019/1", "1"], ["2019/10", "2"], ["2019/20", "3"], ["2019/30", "4"], ["2019/40", "5"]];
  var oA = [];
  array.forEach(function (r, i) {
    oA.push(r);
    let t1 = r[0].split('/');
    let diff;
    if (i + 1 < array.length) {
      let inc = 1;
      let t2 = array[i + 1][0].split('/');
      if (t1[0] == t2[0] && t2[1] - t1[1] > 1) {
        do {
          let t3 = ['', ''];
          t3[0] = t1[0] + '/' + Number(parseInt(t1[1]) + inc);
          t3[1] = r[1];
          diff = t2[1] - t1[1] - inc;
          oA.push(t3);
          inc++;
        } while (diff > 1);
      }
    }
  });
  let end = "is near";
  console.log(JSON.stringify(oA));
}
```

console.log:

```
[["2019/1","1"],["2019/2","1"],["2019/3","1"],["2019/4","1"],["2019/5","1"],["2019/6","1"],["2019/7","1"],["2019/8","1"],["2019/9","1"],["2019/10","2"],["2019/11","2"],["2019/12","2"],["2019/13","2"],["2019/14","2"],["2019/15","2"],["2019/16","2"],["2019/17","2"],["2019/18","2"],["2019/19","2"],["2019/20","3"],["2019/21","3"],["2019/22","3"],["2019/23","3"],["2019/24","3"],["2019/25","3"],["2019/26","3"],["2019/27","3"],["2019/28","3"],["2019/29","3"],["2019/30","4"],["2019/31","4"],["2019/32","4"],["2019/33","4"],["2019/34","4"],["2019/35","4"],["2019/36","4"],["2019/37","4"],["2019/38","4"],["2019/39","4"],["2019/40","5"]]
```